# Add contour plot to base of surface plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, surface, matplotlib-3d

So I've produced a 3-d graph on python using trisruf:
ax.plot_trisurf(x,y,z)
and I end up with the following:
[3d plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ2Je.png)
So now I want to plot contours on the base of this same plot, When I tried using ax.contour(x,y,z) I get an error saying my z should be in 2-dimensions, however my data comes from three 1-d arrays.
How can I go about plotting contours on the base of my graph?

Comment: Maybe `ax.tricontour(x,y,z)`?

Comment: Please create a new post rather than completely rewriting it. Otherwise the above comment, and deleted answer, make no sense

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I managed to find the answer after a bit of searching,
ax.tricontourf(angle_x,angle_y,nlist,zdir='-z', offset = -0.859, cmap='coolwarm') worked, its important to make the offset just slightly lower than the lowest z point (or whatever direction you want the projection) so you can actually see the contour plot!
Here's the result:
[updated plot with contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUT1m.png)